Internet recovery fails to reinstall with "preflight error 21"
I have a 2020 (Intel) Macbook Pro 13" Retina with Touchbar. It's been overheating and one of the diagnostic steps suggested by Apple's online support is to reinstall the OS (ouch!). I'm trying to do that (installing Sonoma) with Internet Recovery, and it keeps failing with "preflight error 21" just after unlocking the hard disk (SSD):

I gather this is related to lack of Internet access. I've tried with both wired and wireless connections, to the same LAN that I use every day for working from home, and Internet access seems fine. Also it's able to get well into the installer process, loading the recovery OS over the internet(?) and getting to the point where I select and unlock the disk. It is however unable to display the OS license agreement (it's blank) just before that step:

Any ideas what else to try?

Do you have access to another Mac on which you can create a bootable installer. That might do the trick depending on what is going on

@SteveChambers thanks, in the end I booted up the mac (it was still bootable) and did exactly that, which worked. Still mystified why Internet Recovery didn't work.

Sometimes Internet Recovery just fails for no apparent reason. It happens to me on rare occasions. Never been able to figure out why.
